# Why Can't I Access Column Name After Cbind() In R

Tags: r

I have combined different matrix with same row size using `cbind()`. I observe that the column name of resulting matrix is not accessible using `$`.

Is there any specific reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: I think you're confusing data.frames and matrices.

Comment: @alistaire - Yes, I come from `matlab` and for me everything is `matrix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` operator does not work for matrices. Instead use `matrix_name[,'column_name']` or `matrix_name[,i]`, being `i` the column index.

Comment: Alternately, you can convert your matrix to a dataframe using `data.frame`. I find it easier to work with dataframes unless my analysis specifically requires that I use a matrix.